# 'Reuben and Shimon' as example names

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, names, responsa

Can anyone help me to find out where the custom of using the names 'Reuben and Shimon' as placeholders – eg in responsa – originated, or any other discussion on the custom?

Comment: It is used in several places in the Gemara? E.g. Bava Basra 43b - https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.43b.3?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en or Bava Kamma 21a - https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.21a.3?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi

Comment: They just seem like the obvious choices.

Comment: @N.T. Nope. Avraham and Yitzhak? Ploni and Almoni? Shem and Ham? Gad and Asher? Moshe and Aharon?

Comment: They also have the advantage that they can be expanded out to Levi and Yehuda and more if necessary.